# Unpacking dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dynamic

What can I do if I want a dictionary like 
`{'example': "test", 'example1': "test1", 'example2':"test2"}`

to become 
`("example"="test", "example1"="test1", "example2"="test")`?

Comment: Your example output is not valid Python

Comment: You can use namedtuple. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the output

```
('example=test', 'example1=test1', 'example2=test2')
```

you can do

```
('%s=%s' % (str(k), str(v)) for k, v in dict.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean, but I will make a guess based on the title you used (unpacking).

If what you want is to use a dictionary as keyword arguments for functions you have to use the `**` operator that will unpack it, this is what you do:

```
some_function(**{'example': test, 'example1': test1, 'example2':test2})
```

That will be the same as

```
some_function(example=test, example1=test1, example2=test)
```

Or even cleaner:

```
my_dict = {'example': test, 'example1': test1, 'example2':test2}
some_function(**my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `namedtuple` from `collections` module.

Here is an example you can try:

```
from collections import namedtuple
d = {'example': "test", 'example1': "test1", 'example2':"test2"}
exemple = namedtuple("exemple", d.keys())
e1 = exemple(*d.values())
print(e1)
```

you will get:

`exemple(example='test', example1='test1', example2='test2')`